# How to prevent cancellation of ajax request upon redirect?

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, webmethod

This is my first ajax request. I don't want the client browser to wait, so my code is not waiting for success. It redirects to another page immediately. But it's not working.

```
$.ajax({
            data: '{}',
            url: "Service.asmx/GetNextID",
            success: function(msg1) { 
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", cache: false, contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json", timeout: 5000,
                    url: "Service.asmx/SaveData",
                    dataFilter: function(data) {var msg = (typeof (JSON) !== 'undefined' && typeof (JSON.parse) === 'function') ? JSON.parse(data) : eval('(' + data + ')');return (msg.hasOwnProperty('d')) ? msg.d : msg;},
                    data: "{ID:'" + $get('<%=txt1.ClientID %>').value + "',Date:'<%=cutoffdate%>',data:'" + $("#<%=txt2.ClientID %>").val() + "'}",
                    error: function(xhr, desc, exception){
                        alert("Failed!");
                }
                });
                window.location = "../Result.aspx?ID=" + msg1.ID;
            },
            error: function(xhr, desc, exception) {
            }
        });
```

So since it's not waiting for success and redirects to another page, the next call "SavaData" is getting cancelled.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: It doesn't sound right to me. The ajax call need to wait until it get the response to know whether it is a 200 or 302 response. How can it redirect without waiting for success ?

Answer (score -3):

wait for a few secs before redirecting ?

Comment: Do you think it gonna work by giving few ms? Can you explain it please?

Comment: see the thing is in javascript things generally happen asynchronously. Here just after the ajax call is fired, redirect happens and that can possibly stop the ajax call. What you want to do is a fire and forget ajax call...right ? So make the ajax call. Give it a few milliseconds or may be a second and then redirect. It will, in most cases, make sure ajax is fired. Once an http request is sent to the server it cannot be called back. 

Otherwise fire that ajax call and instead of redirect take the resulting page and replace it will existing dom.